# Very elementary question about cosets on $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 \} $ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$. I computed the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}_2$:

$$ 0 + Z_2 = 1 + Z_2 = 2 + Z_2 = 3 + Z_2 = Z_2 $$

So the number of cosets of $H$ is just $1$, but we have that $| G : H | = 2 $. Why am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Note that it is incorrect to say that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ It would be better if you use $H$ instead.

Comment: That subset of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: IS $Z_3$ a subgroup of $Z_6$ ?

Comment: There is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but it is not the one you wrote here.

Comment: What you probably want to do is to write the cosets of $H=\{0,2\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: @WillieRosario: $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{0,1,2\}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$. It is not even a subset. Your confusion perhaps stems from the fact that you think the elements $0,1,2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are the same elements used in $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. They are not.